# String permutation recursion issue

Tags: c++, recursion

(--This question was answered down below--)

Hey guys so I know this question has been answered in various ways so far on this site but I wanted to see if I could get a hint to my question without getting the blunt answer... sorry if this is redundant!

so... so far my code is this (as the function says, this is supposed to print out every permutation of the string "ABCD" and MUST be done recursively and without the use of STL algorithms):

```
void printPermutations(string prefix, string remainder)
{
    
    if (remainder.empty())        
        cout<<prefix<<endl;         
    else {
        for(int i = 0; i<remainder.length(); i++)      
        {
            prefix += remainder[i];                     
            remainder = (remainder.substr(0, i) + remainder.substr(i+1));    //Gets rid of selected char
            printPermutations(prefix, remainder);   //recursion w/updated values. Problem here?
         }
     }
}
```

Where remainder = "ABCD" as a test string. I'm assuming my problem is with the recursive call itself?

So far, the function only prints out the first 3 permutations: ABCD, ABDC, ACBD. I also have a hunch that this could have something to do with the for control since it printed out 3 permutations and 3 would be less than the string's length of 4? I don't know. I just started learning recursion and it's really hard for me to figure out how to implement recursive calls properly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions, for example to include an actual question. What is the problem with the code you show? What do you need our help with?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? If that's what I think I'm not sure it can be done recursively.

Comment: Permutations don't need recursion, combinations can be done with recursion.

Comment: @samthegolden Any loop can be done recursively, so this could be done with recursion, but I'm not sure its necessary.

Comment: you're right @john

Comment: Where does `rest` come from?

Comment: You want to use the prefixes "A", "B", "C", and "D" for the recursions. Print your prefix on each iteration and compare. (Recursion and mutation are not the best of friends.)

Comment: Sorry I guys I forgot to mention that I am being forced to do it this way for a project in class. Thanks for the input. I know it can be done I just didn't know how. And rest should have been remainder. I changed it part of the way through.. sorry about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're modifying both strings in the loop, so `prefix` grows and `remainder` shrinks.

That is, you want the "top-level" call to iterate through A/BCD, B/ACD, C/ABD, and D/ABC, but you're iterating through A/BCD, AB/CD, ABC/D, and ABCD/empty.

Don't modify the strings, just pass the values you want to the recursion:

```
void printPermutations(string prefix, string remainder)
{
    if (remainder.empty())        
        cout<<prefix<<endl;         
    else {
        for(int i = 0; i<remainder.length(); i++)      
        {
            printPermutations(prefix + remainder[i], 
                              remainder.substr(0, i) + remainder.substr(i+1));
        }
    }
}
```

Or use "fresh" variables if you want a more "step-by-step" look:

```
void printPermutations(string prefix, string remainder)
{
    if (remainder.empty())        
        cout<<prefix<<endl;         
    else {
        for(int i = 0; i<remainder.length(); i++)      
        {
            string thisPrefix = prefix + remainder[i];
            string thisRemainder = remainder.substr(0, i) + remainder.substr(i+1);
            printPermutations(thisPrefix, thisRemainder);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for your answer. I don't know why I didn't think of passing the updated values without passing the original strings. It's so hard for me to "see" what the recursive call is going to do in future calls. I draw out the tree and it makes sense but then I don't know how to implement it correctly.

Comment: Also, just to clarify for future reference: is it right to think of it as one leg of the tree completes first and then it goes back to to the top and the second leg completes? Like say A is the prefix -> that whole A tree completes and then it goes back to the original for loop and sets B as the prefix -> the B tree completes and so on and so on?

Comment: @s0rry Yes, that's what the loop says - "print the permutations beginning with 'A', print the permutations beginning with 'B',...  (You can also add tracing outputs and look. Adding a "depth" parameter to the function so you can see where you are can be helpful - that's what I did to see what your code was up to.)

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using the stl algorithm [next_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) for the job. The code in your case is than:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    std::string s = "ABCD";
    std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());
    do {
        std::cout << s << '\n';
    } while(std::next_permutation(s.begin(), s.end()));
}
```

If you need to, you can write a wrapper around this snippet.

Comment: I appreciate the answer but we are not allowed to use any STL algorithms. This is for a recursion project in class.

Comment: @s0rry You can learn from the stl algorithm how this task is done. The documentation on cppreference.com (link in the answer) shows a possible implementaion.

Comment: I see. I feel like professor would frown upon us not struggling and figuring things out ourselves but with recursion it seems like you hit a wall sometimes and have to ask for hints. I appreciate your answer.